# Booting Ubuntu from USB stick on Lenovo IdeaPad g580 (i5)

Tags: live-usb, lenovo

I can't install Ubuntu on my laptop. Every time I insert the USB stick and boot up the laptop it's stuck for about 2 minutes one the lenovo screen. After that it boots FreeDos (original OS).

Comment: The ISO file you downloaded which was used to make the USB drive bootable - did you run MD5 or some other checker to make sure it arrived intact? Have you tried generating a bootable USB using a different flashdrive?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some similar boot issues with my Lenovo IdeaPad Y500, especially with booting from an ISO burned on DVD (but also using USB boot). Assuming there are some similarities between the two laptops, I would suggest the following:

- Power off the laptop & remove the USB stick
- Boot the machine from the **"Novo"** button
- Once the "Novo" menu appears, insert your USB stick
- Select "Boot Menu"
- If the ISO was properly written, you should see a bootable USB drive in the boot menu.

---

If the above doesn't work, I would explore your BIOS settings, and try enabling, or disabling secure boot to see if that works.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Power off the laptop & remove the USB stick Boot the machine from the "Novo" button Once the "Novo" menu appears, Select BIOS..

Inside BIOS under boot tab you will find there UEFI Boot you will need to disable that
then u need to move the USB HDD: GENERIC USB HDD to number 1.

You can do that by highlighting the USB HDD: GENERIC USB HDD and pressing F5 or F6 to move it up

-or-

Highlight the things on top of the USB HDD: GENERIC USB HDD then put them down still using the F5 or F6 to move them down, do it one by one till the USB HDD is on top.

Just make once you got the USB HDD: GENERIC USB HDD to 1 hit F10 to save and exit changes.

Comment: this doesn't work